# In vim, how do I prevent pasting on top of visually selected text from erasing the contents of the clipboard?

Tags: vim

In Vim, if I have a file like this:

```
one
two
```

I visually select "one" by using `ve` and then yank it by using `y`, it gets copied to the default register (referred to as the "clipboard").

If I then visually select "two" by using `ve` and paste the contents of the default register on top of it using `p`, the file is updated to look like this:

```
one
one
```

The value of "two" has been yanked to the default register, and if I want to paste the value of "one" again in another location, I would have to yank it again.

Is there a way to paste the contents of the default register on top of a visual selection in Vim without overwriting its value in the default register?

I understand that there are alternative approaches, such as using search and replace, but I'm specifically asking about the visual selection features in Vim.

Comment: This behavior is quite logical. Your old item **one** moves from unnamed register to register number zero once you paste it onto selected text. The deleted/selected text is now in the unnamed register. You can check this by the command :reg. And you can paste your old item **one** by simply typing "0p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to paste the contents of the default register on top of a visual selection in Vim without overwriting its value in the default register?

Yes, paste it with `P` instead of `p`. You can see `:help v_P` for details.